# Fundamental Theorem of Algebra for highschool

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

My teacher has told me about the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, but I can't seem to find any proofs on it which I can understand. For something so important I'm hoping to find a proof that a highschool student can understand.

References are welcome too, thanks!

Comment: I had the same question you did at one point! I do not believe there are any "high school" level proofs. The proofs, and there are several, rely on concepts in complex analysis, abstract algebra, topology, Galois theory etc. all of which are undergraduate level. Thus, the best you can hope for as far as an answer to your question is thus roughly a "proof sketch" written such that it is comprehensible to an individual with high-school level mathematical knowledge.

Comment: There is a proof which uses nothing more advanced than the intermediate value theorem, although it is of course more "difficult" than the advanced proofs. Is that of any interest?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 That is reassuring to know, at least I know that my question is perhaps not too silly! I have started some reading in abstract algebra, am I still too far away from a proof in that I can understand in that sense?

Comment: @almagest I recognise that theorem from real analysis! Please do go ahead and post it :)

Answer (score 3):

There is one intuitive proof for this theorem. Let $p(z)=\sum_{i=0}^na_iz^i$ where $a_i\in \mathbb{C}$. We need to show that $p$ has a zero in $\mathbb{C}$. Take a very large real number $R$ and consider the circle $|z|=R$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Since $R$ is large, plugging these $z$ into $p$, we have that $p(z)$ is some very large contour that is somewhat centered at $0$. (Since $R$ is large, the contribution of $a_n z^n$ dominates, so $p(z)\sim a_nz^n$). Similarly, consider the circle $|z|=r$ for some real number $r$ close to zero, then $p(z)\sim a_0$, hence $p(z)$ is some small contour near $a_0$.

When we let $r$ vary from very small to very large, then we get growing contours in $\mathbb{C}$ whose centers vary from $a_0$ to $0$. At some point some contour must go through the origin.

One can make an argument like this precise, however it is very difficult to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I made a few silly mistakes.

Comment: Nice proof, I hadn't seen this before. It's not so difficult to make precise right? What's the real reason we feel that a small wiggly contour near $a_0$ can't smoothly deform into a great big contour which looks like a circle centered at $0$ traversed $n$ times, without the contour passing through $0$? We're reasonably well motivated to define the winding number at this point.

Comment: That's quite a nifty intuitive proof!

Comment: I believe paragraph 56 of Munkres has a similar proof, I thought of this one myself in high school, but never tried to make it very precise (Since the one in Munkres is easy to understand as well).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof that I've always liked.

Suppose $\forall z : P(z)\neq 0$
Let
$$f(z) :=  |P(z)|$$
Then $f(z)$ is larger than some number $m>0$ and attains its minimum $m$ on some point $z_0$ (which must be finite because $P(z)$ goes to $\infty$ as $z$ goes to $\infty$)

Let $$Q(z):= P(z-z_0)$$
We have $Q(0) = a$ s.t $|a| = m$ and $|Q(z)|\geq m$

Then $$Q(z) = a+ \sum_1^n a_k z^k \underset{z\to 0}{=} a + a_p z^p + o(z^p)$$
Where $p$ is the first number for which $a_p\neq 0$

So $$|Q(z)| \underset{z\to 0}{=} |a+a_pz^p| + o(z^p)$$
If we choose $a_p z^p = aw^p$ ,i.e $z = \left(\frac{a}{a_p}\right)^{1/p}w$,
we get $$Q(z) \underset{w\to 0}{=}  |a||1+w^p| + o(w^p) = m|1+w^p| + o(w^p)$$
So if we take $w = (-t)^{1/p}$ s.t $t$ is a positive real number.
$$Q(z) \underset{t\to 0}{=} m|1-t| + o(t) = m(1-t) + o(t) $$
Which is strictly smaller than $m$ for small enough $t$.

Comment: what is $o(z^p)$ and $P(z)$?

Comment: @RM777 $P(z)$ is a non constant polynomial, and we're trying to prove that it must have at least one root in the complex plane.  $$ $$
We say a function $f$ is $o(z^p)$ near $a$, or $o(g(z))$ for some function $g$ in general, if $f(z) = \varepsilon(z) g(z)$ and $\varepsilon(z)\to 0$ as $z\to a$, (or more simply, $f/g \to 0$ if they're non-zero in some neighborhood of $a$). $$ $$ So $$|Q(z)| = |\dots| + o(z^p)$$ is shorthand for $$|Q(z)|=|\dots| + g(z)$$
for some function $g$, which is $o(z^p)$ near $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof that mimics the proof of the maximum modulus principle.

Let $P$ be the polynomial and $f(x) = |P(x)|$. We know that $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ so it has a minimum. Assume for contradiction that this minimum is at $z$ where $P(z)\ne 0$

Recall the taylor series expansion $P(z+\epsilon) = P(z) + P'(z)\epsilon + P''(z)\epsilon^2 / 2 + \cdots + P^{(m)}(z) \epsilon^m / m! + \cdots$

Let $t$ be the smallest positive integer such that $P^{(t)}(z) \ne 0$. Then picking $|\epsilon| < 999^{-1000t}$ and $\frac{\epsilon^t P^{(t)}(z)}{P(z)}\in \mathbb{R}^-$ yields $$|P(z+\epsilon)| \le P(z) (1-|\frac{\epsilon^t P^{(t)}(z)}{P(z)t!}|) + \sum\limits_{j=t+1}^{\deg P} |\epsilon^{j} P^{j}(z) / j!|$$

By triangular inequality.

Picking $|\epsilon|$ sufficiently small gives $|P(z+\epsilon)| < |P(z)|$, contradicting $|P(z)|$'s minimality